# OnePlus One Bootloop with Nougat

Tags: 7.0-nougat, oneplus-one

I have tried to flash Nougat OS (many ROMS). I have wiped the data, cache, dalvik cache and system partition and format them to ext4 (recovery TWRP 3.0.3-5 by TugaPower).
After that I have flashed the ROMS and the mini GApps.
Then when I tries to boot, and it takes more then 20 minutes to boot (and the OS still doesn't booted).

I tried the unofficial LineageOS, RR 5.8, AICP but I stuck in bootloop in every Nougat ROM. The Marshmallow version of each is working, just the Nougat have bootloop issues.

Only the AOSP Nougat for OnePlus One succeeded to boot...

What should I do for solving this?

Comment: Are you using the gapps for nougat?

Answer (score 0):

After flashing the CM14 rom, and boot, all the others roms are working now.